# C# Linq Combine multiple sequences by key

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have two `IList<Traffic>` I need to combine.

Traffic is a simple class:

```
class Traffic
{
  long MegaBits;
  DateTime Time;
}
```

Each `IList` holds the same Times, and I need a single `IList<Traffic>`, where I have summed up the MegaBits, but kept the Time as key.

Is this possible using Linq ?

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that Time isn't necessarily unique in any list, multiple `Traffic` instances may have the same Time.

Also I might run into X lists (more than 2), I should had mentioned that as well - sorry :-(

EXAMPLE:

```
IEnumerable<IList<Traffic>> trafficFromDifferentNics;

var combinedTraffic = trafficFromDifferentNics
                        .SelectMany(list => list)
                        .GroupBy(traffic => traffic.Time)
                        .Select(grp => new Traffic { Time = grp.Key, MegaBits = grp.Sum(tmp => tmp.MegaBits) });
```

The example above works, so thanks for your inputs :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine the items in both lists into a single set, then group on the key to get the sum before transforming back into a new set of `Traffic` instances.

```
var result = firstList.Concat(secondList)
    .GroupBy(trf => trf.Time, trf => trf.MegaBits)
    .Select(grp => new Traffic { Time = grp.Key, MegaBits = grp.Sum()});
```

Answer (score 3):

this sounds more like

```
var store = firstList.Concat(secondList).Concat(thirdList)/* ... */;
var query = from item in store
            group item by item.Time
            into groupedItems
            select new Traffic
            {
                MegaBits = groupedItems.Sum(groupedItem => groupedItem.MegaBits),
                Time = groupedItems.Key
            };
```

or, with your rework

```
IEnumerable<IList<Traffic>> stores;
var query = from store in stores
            from item in store
            group item by item.Time
            into groupedItems
            select new Traffic
            {
                MegaBits = groupedItems.Sum(groupedItem => groupedItem.MegaBits),
                Time = groupedItems.Key
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like:

```
var query = from x in firstList
            join y in secondList on x.Time equals y.Time
            select new Traffic { MegaBits = x.MegaBits + y.MegaBits,
                                 Time = x.Time };
```

Note that this will join in a pair-wise fashion, so if there are multiple elements with the same time in each list, you may not get the results you want.

Comment: Hmmm I guess I should had written that - Time is not guaranteed to be unique in any list. I'll update the question for clarity.

Comment: @Steffen: At this point it would really help if you'd give a sample of the input and expected output then.